# how to input data in checkbox with other input ('Text or Number')

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<td>
    <input type="number" name="qty_masuk[]" id="qty_masuk" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY">
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-control">
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_barang" name="id_barang[]" value="<?php echo $st['id_barang']; ?>">
    </div>
</td>
```

code html view

```
public function add_selected_barang()
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id_barang = $_POST['id_barang'];
        $qty_masuk = $_POST['qty_masuk'];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_barang); $i++) {
            if ($qty_masuk != NULL) {
                $category_id = $id_barang[$i];
                $category_qty = $qty_masuk[$i];
                $this->Po_model->multisave($category_id, $category_qty);
            }
            // 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Item baru berhasil ditambahkan');
            redirect('daftarproduk');
        }
    }
}
```

in this controller I try to get 2 or more data when the checkbox is selected, when all the data is checked there is no problem at all the data entered is correct according to the selected data, which becomes a problem when I try to input the 2nd data without checking the first data, qty_masuk the value becomes 0 which should follow the data entered by the user, the problem that occurs is in qty_masuk.

```
function multisave($id_barang, $qty_masuk)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO `barang_masuk`( `id_barang`, `qty_masuk`) 
    VALUES ('$id_barang','$qty_masuk')";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```

Model

what should be added to solve this problem?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Please remember, if a checkbox is NOT CHECKED it is not sent to the backend server code. So it is quite possible for these 2 arrays to be of a different length

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#attr-value

Comment: You should really use Codeigniters [query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) to [insert](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#inserting-data) the data instead of manually building the query. Why use a framework if you're not taking advantage of it's features?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment. Are you saying that you now are trying to learn Codeigniter, but won't learn about it's features until later? Codeigniter is a framework. A framework is a set of features. You can't learn Codeigniter _without_ learning it's features. And why wouldn't you learn to do things properly from the start?